# How to merge 2 iplimage (opencv)

Tags: opencv

```
IplImage *intensity = //grayscale image 1 channel
IplImage *range = // range information 1 channel
```

Using cvMerge you need 3 channels.

The result which i want is an image with 2 channels (on containing intensity information and the other containing disparity information)

How can i merge this 2 images?

Comment: what kind of image are you trying to build from a gray and a range channel ? you can easily duplicate(reuse) an existing channel (and please use the c++ api instead of the arcane c one)

Comment: I only want to use this 2 channels for image segmentation using SLIC algorithm. An example which uses color image, disparity info, and optical flow can be found here: http://www.mvdblive.org/research/mvdb_wacv_2012.pdf

In my case i have intensity and disparity informations (i will not use right now the optical flow)

Comment: interesting link, thanks .

Comment: so, with the information you have, you can construct Dxyz from 4.1 already. intensity is the L expression in Dlab. can't you get more information, like the color channels (to get the a and b features, too) ? x,y,z,i are 4 features only, while the paper uses 7 dim features.

Comment: The data which i process contain only intensity information gathered from a stereo system. (i have left image, right image) a build the range information. The formula which i want to use is something like this: Ds = Dint + Dxyz. Dint = sqrt((lk-li)^2), Dxyz is the same formula as in the paper, based on the range image (x,y,d).

Comment: what's your plan for the clustering ? it all depends on that

Comment: k-means clustering using the above formula as distance between pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know for sure that the C++ version supports merging two channels, so you can use it. Have you tried passing two input images and NULL for the rest?